# How to .click() button repeatedly

Tags: javascript, click

I have just started a university and to get the best lesson times, there are click wars. I wonder if it's possible to click a button 10 times per second using javascript .click(). I have tried:

```
let b = buttons[0]
function bClick() {
    if (b.value == "apply"){
        b.click()
    }
}
setInterval(bClick, 100)
```

however, only the first .click() actually does something and the rest are ignored. Is there a way how to get around it?

Edit: The value does not change after the initial click and I do not need it to be super precise, just to fire a lot is enough.

Comment: Does clicking on it change the value? There's not really enough info here.

Answer (score 0):

Your setInterval works properly. my assumption is that the value != "apply" on the second click due to the fact that it might change via the first click event handler.

By the way, `setInterval` doesn't guarantee an accurate delay. it is the least amount of delay between the recurring function calls, so it's not accurate that 10 clicks will occur in 1 second.

You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals

Answer (score -1):

```
setInterval(function clickButton(){
    for(let i=1;i<=10;i++){
     document.getElementById("apply").click();
    console.log(`I clicked ${i} times`);
    }
},1000);
```

This function is going to click a button with the id "apply" 10 times every 1000ms. But, this will run every second until clearInterval() is called or the browser tab/window is closed.

Comment: Code only answers aren't very useful. How does this solve the problem? You seem to be suggesting using `setInterval`, but the code in the question already does.

Comment: I was in the middle of editing the solution for clarification . Thanks for the heads up though